# How to generate a series of plot with `for`

Tags: julia

I learn to program in `Julia` language.

I want to test which color is better, so I use the following code:

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10,2);
for i in [0 0.1 0.2]
    plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter,background_color=RGB(0.4,0.8,i))
end
```

How, nothing show.

Can anyone tell me how to generate plot with `loop`?

P.S.

I have tried another way,

```
[plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter,background_color=RGB(0.4,0.8,i)) for i in 0:0.1:1]
```

Nothing happened with above code.

The following code does not work either:

```
map(i->plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter,background_color=RGB(0.4,0.8,i)), [0 0.1 0.2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a script plot is not shown unless you use `display` function to show it (see section *Plotting in scripts* here http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/tutorial/).

You have several options here. This one is the simplest:

```
for i in [0 0.1 0.2]
    display(plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter,background_color=RGB(0.4,0.8,i)))
    sleep(1)
end
```

It will plot your figures in a sequence. I use `sleep(1)` to make Julia pause between plotting.

Otherwise you can do:

```
p = [plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter,background_color=RGB(0.4,0.8,i)) for i in 0:0.1:1]
```

and then plot your figures from Julia REPL like this:

```
julia> p[5]
```

will plot fifth figure. Now you do not have to use `display` because in REPL it will be invoked anyway as I did not use `;` at the end of the line. You could write `display(p[5])` to get the same effect.

Finally you can consider saving the figures to PNG file and inspecting them later. You can do it either using `p` array defined above like this:

```
foreach(i -> savefig(p[i], "fig$i.png"), eachindex(p))
```

or in a loop like this:

```
for i in [0 0.1 0.2]
    p = plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter,background_color=RGB(0.4,0.8,i))
    savefig(p, "fig$i.png)
end
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. I got the difference between Mathematica and Julia.